# How to give access to API behing AWS Api Gateway from our SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

we use Aws Api Gateway to protect our apis.

We want to create an sdk for developers. The idea is to have In app purchase in their apps and call our apis in order to start payment.

We are trying to have a way to connect machine from machine. The first machine will be an sdk integrated in Android games and the second will be our back end protected by the api gateway.

The sdk should have a the authorization to consume the api.
Today we don't know how to do it, even after discussing with many architects.

The sdk is not going to have user and password, because it is not a user, so no way to generate the classic access token.

How could we achieve this use case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The sdk should have a the authorization to consume the api. Today we don't know how to do it, even after discussing with many architects.

There are three possible ways to have a protected API Gateway. **AWS Cognito** and **AWS Lambda**. The third option, [API Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html), is a little bit different than the previous two.

With [Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html), you create user pools and API Gateway automatically handles authorization when a request is received.

With [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html), you create your own custom authorization logic.

I generally prefer the Lambda approach due to the ease of use but it depends on the use-case.

With the [API Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans-with-rest-api.html) option, you create API Keys for specific routes and API Gateway checks them through the request headers. I think any use-case that requires this can be handled with the Lambda option as well.

---

What you are describing doesn't sound difficult to achieve.

You will generate an API key and you will give them to the developers that will use your API.

In your SDK, you can accept the API key as an initialization parameter and provide it in the requests to API Gateway.

Comment: thanks for your reponse. We have today a userpool attached to the API gateway. This solution means that we have to create a user and a password for the sdk right ? So the sdk can access the API. 
The API key seems the solution, but in the doc they said that API key should not be used for Authorization. That's why i'm stuck for the moment.